# What are the equipment restrictions for NPC/Hirelings in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

I am playing my way through Nightmare Diablo 2 on Battle.net closed servers and because of the swarming that's occurring I've decided to bite the bullet and get a hireling to come help out.

My act 1 hireling seemed to be restricted to bow weapons.  My act 2 defensive hireling comes with a spiffy cold effect but seeems to be restricted to pole arms, without a shield regardless of the class of pole arm (ie 1 handed pole arms should allow a shield, but don't).

What are the restrictions on hirelings and what other bonuses might I discover?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those Hirelings are also known as Mercenaries.
As listed on [Diablowiki.net](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Mercenaries) only the weapon and off-hand slots have restrictions as followed:

**Rouge Scouts (Act I)**

- Only Bows (NO Crossbows or `Amazon only` Bows)
- can use Cold Arrow
  or Fire Arrow in addition to Inner Sight

**Desert Mercenaries (Act II)**

- Spears, Javelins and Polearms (no `Amazon only` equipment)
- use Jab Attack and have a Aura dependent on type and difficulty they were
  bought in:

`.     |Normal/Hell|Nightmare  |
Combat |Prayer     |Thorns     |
Offense|Blessed Aim|Might      |
Defense|Defiance   |Holy Freeze|`

**Iron Wolves (Act III)**

- Shield and Sword
- skills depend on type:

  > Inferno or Fireball for **Fire**
  >   Glacial Spike, Ice Blast, Frozen Armor for **Cold**
  >   Charged Bolt and Lightning Bolt for **Lightning**
- *they will not hit much with the sword - look for caster-bonus on it (for example, [`Spirit`](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/runewords-110.shtml) runeword)!*

**Barbarians (Act V)**

- Barbarian class-specific items, **one** sword (no dual-wielding)
- use Bash and Stun

Additionally to the type restrictions, mercenaries follow the items requirements for Strength, Dexterity and Level.
Back when I played Diablo II, act II Mercenaries were the most common choice due to their buff-auras.

Comment: Act 2 Hell Defense - Best merc in the game.

Answer (score 11):

Mercenaries follow the following sets of equipment rules:

**Act 1 - Rogue Scouts**

Armor, Helms, Bows (NOT crossbows or Amazon specific bows)

**Act 2 - Desert Mercenaries**

Armor, Helms, Spears or Polearms (NOT Amazon specific spears)

**Act 3 - Ironwolves**

Armor, Helms, Shields, 1 handed swords

Note that the Ironwolves do not actually physically attack with the sword, so finding one with good casting stats for whatever element you choose is is a better idea than finding one with good weapon damage.

**Act 5 - Barbarians**

Armor, Helms, Barbarian class specific helms, Swords (both 2h and 1h variety, though they cannot dual wield)

Also note that Mercenaries follow STR/DEX requirements for items as well as level, though generally speaking this is not usually an issue.